# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" while sending JSON to a webservice using JQuery/AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

EDIT: After figuring out how to step through the code it appears that `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DataManagement.dll but was not handled in user code`. It happens in this line:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
```

I'm not sure what the means but hopefully that sheds some more light on the problem.

I am trying to send a JavaScript object to a web Service and I am getting the 500 error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I'm fairly positive that I am passing something out of format to the method in the web service but I'm not really sure. Any help I can get would be awesome I'm a beginner and have been ramming my head against the wall on this for forever.

JSON (from fiddler):

```
{"sampleIds":["1"],"line1":"","line2":"","line3":"","labelType":"Soil","startingLabelPosition":1}
```

Javascript:

```
var labelInfo = new Object();
labelInfo.sampleIds = sampleIds;
labelInfo.line1 = $('#ddlGrower').val();
labelInfo.line2 = $('#ddlFarm').val();
labelInfo.line3 = $('#ddlField1').val();
labelInfo.labelType = $('#ddlSoilLoginMatrix option:selected').text();
labelInfo.startingLabelPosition = parseInt($('#labelSelection').text());

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DesktopModules/DataManagement/TestService.svc/CreateLabelPdf",
    data: JSON.stringify(labelInfo),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        window.open(data.d);
    },
    error:  function(msg) {
        alert("Error: " + msg.status);
    }
});
```

C# web service:

```
[OperationContract]
public string CreateLabelPdf(List<string> sampleIds, string line1, string line2, string line3, string labelType, int startingLabelPosition)
{
   List<LabelContent> labels = new List<LabelContent>();

   foreach (var sample in sampleIds)
   {
      LabelContent labelContent = new LabelContent();
      labelContent.Line1 = line1;
      labelContent.Line2 = line2;
      labelContent.Line3 = line3;
      labelContent.LabelId = sample;
      labels.Add(labelContent);
   }   

   Creator creator = new Creator
   {
      IncludeLabelBorders = false
   };
   string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
   creator.PrintLabels(labels, new Avery5160(), path, startingLabelPosition);
   return path;
}
```

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil ah sorry that was just a human error

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I'm not sure? Is that the stack trace? It goes on for quite a bit after that as well.

`StackTrace=   at Mvtl.Website.Modules.DataManagement.TestService.CreateLabelPdf(List 1 sampleIds, String line1, String line2, String line3, String labelType, Int32 startingLabelPosition) in \\10.8.1.9\c$\sites\www.website.com\DesktopModules\DataManagement\TestService.svc.cs:line 380 `

Comment: Put a break point and see what's happening.

Comment: @inanikian I'm not sure how to do that in visual studio with code on a remote server. I've done it in browser web tools for the javascript but yeah. I think I have to attach to some process? I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh well, your file is named "0.pdf" ?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev yeah it is. Unfortunately this isn't all my code. I think the next line is supposed to overwrite(?) or create some PDF to be displayed but that file path does lead to a PDF named 0.pdf

Comment: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx) explains how to debug a site or program hosted on a remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. I debugged the code and found out that the error was in this line:

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
```

It was getting a null reference error so I changed the code to:

```
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");
```

That worked but then I needed to return the relative string to the browser instead of the physcial path so I threw in:

```
string relativePath = @"\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\0.pdf";
return relativePath;
```

Ending code looking like:

```
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");

creator.PrintLabels(labels, new Avery5160(), path, startingLabelPosition);

string relativePath = @"\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\0.pdf";
return relativePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON seems invalid. I think it should start with:

```
{"sampleIds":["1"],"line1":"","line2":"","line3":"","labelType":"Soil","startingLabelPosition":1}
```

Right now the `sampleIds` is like this:

```
{"sampleIds:["1"],"line1":"","line2":"","line3":"","labelType":"Soil","startingLabelPosition":1}
```

That is, `"sampleIds"` is not properly formatted as a key.

Comment: that was a typo on my part i edited in the correct JSON form fiddler

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see which variable is null?

Comment: um no? in visual studio I tried to start debugging and I got an error saying that it could not add a service?

Comment: I debugged the code I think. I edited it in above. The error was in the path string but I'm not sure how to move forward.